# chrome.browserAction.onClicked.removeListener not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

We developed a Chrome extension, and I want to open a new tab when the user clicks on our icon. But the problem is, I don't know if I already added this event listener before, and for how long will it be valid. I tried to use `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.removeListener`, but it doesn't remove the event listener, and the function is called twice or 3 times if I added it more than once (opening 2 or 3 tabs). Here is my code:

```
var open_editor_in_tab = function() {
    utils.open_tab(url);
};
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.removeListener(open_editor_in_tab);
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(open_editor_in_tab);
```

How do I remove the listener before adding it again?

**Update:** Also with this code it opens the tab 2 or 3 times:

```
var open_editor_in_tab = function() {
    utils.open_tab(url);
};
if (!(chrome.browserAction.onClicked.hasListener(open_editor_in_tab))) {
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(open_editor_in_tab);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.hasListener(open_editor_in_tab);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should be declared once:

```
var open_editor_in_tab = function() {
    utils.open_tab(url);
};
```

Only then you can call this code a few times:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.removeListener(open_editor_in_tab);
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(open_editor_in_tab);
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout `hasListener` method in the [event documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events). Snipper from docs:

> **hasListener** boolean Event.hasListener(function callback)
>
> Parameters
> function  callback
>
> Listener whose registration status shall be tested.
> The callback parameter should be a function that looks like this:
> function() {...};